# Powershell cmdlet named: New-SqlCredential not present on Dev Workstation

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012

According to [this post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3056/backup-and-restore-with-cloud-services-windows-azure-blob-storage-service-using-powershell/) I should be able to execute: New-SqlCredential if my server is updated to:   Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Cumulative Update 4 which according to http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2758687&kbln=en-us is a build number lower than what my Dev machine reports:

> SELECT @@VERSION 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (Intel
>   X86)      Dec 28 2012 19:06:41    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>     Developer Edition on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (WOW64)

And yet, while can issue: Backup-SqlDatabase (also part of that release) I can't see: **New-SqlCredential**

Answer (score 0):

Must have .net framework 4.5 installed.